# Need of create custom REST API for reviews in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to create a REST API in magento 2, which take Store ID as parameters and returns all the reviews for Specific Store ID.

And if pass additional parameters, like customer id,product id then filter should be perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very broad topic to explain. I am explain step by step procedure.

Step 1. In Magento 2 core folder go to app/code.
create vendor folder like ECMAG and sub folder like MyReviews.
in MyReviews folder create, three folder Api,etc and model.

Step 2. In etc folder, create di.xml file with below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="ECMAG\MyReviews\Api\MyReviewInterface"
                type="ECMAG\MyReviews\Model\MyReviewClass" />

</config>
```

Next,create module.xml file in same folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="ECMAG_MyReviews" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Next, create webapi.xml file in same folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/showreview/allreviews/:storeId" method="GET">
        <service class="ECMAG\MyReviews\Api\MyReviewInterface" method="getAllReviews"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>

</routes>
```

Step 3. Next create interface in Api folder like.

```
<?php
namespace ECMAG\MyReviews\Api;
interface MyReviewInterface
{

    /**
     * GET  review by its ID
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $storeId
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getAllReviews($storeId);

}
```

Step 4. Next create class in Model folder.

```
<?php
namespace ECMAG\MyReviews\Model;
use ECMAG\MyReviews\Api\MyReviewInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;    

class MyReviewClass implements MyReviewInterface{
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request) {
       $this->request = $request;
    }

     /**
     * GET  review by its ID
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $storeId
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getAllReviews($storeId){
        $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
        $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
        $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $currentStoreId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $rating = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");

        //Apply filter for store id and status='Approved'
        $collection = $rating->create()->addStoreFilter($storeId
        )->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED);
            //Get All parameters from request
            $allParameters=$this->request->getParams();
           //Check parameter from_Date present or not
            if(array_key_exists("fromDate",$allParameters)){
                $collection=$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $allParameters['fromDate']]);
             }
             //Check parameter to_Date present or not
             if(array_key_exists("toDate",$allParameters)){
                $collection=$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $allParameters['toDate']]);
             }
             //Check parameter title present or not
             if(array_key_exists("title",$allParameters)){
                 $title=$allParameters['title'];
                $collection=$collection->addFieldToFilter('title', ['like' => '%'.$title.'%']);
             }
             //Check parameter text present or not
             if(array_key_exists("text",$allParameters)){
                $collection=$collection->addFieldToFilter('detail', ['like' => '%'.$allParameters['text'].'%']);
             }
             //Check parameter customer id present or not
             if(array_key_exists("customerId",$allParameters)){
                $collection=$collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', ['eq' => $allParameters['customerId']]);
             }
             //Check parameter product id present or not
             if(array_key_exists("productId",$allParameters)){
                $collection=$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_pk_value', ['eq' => $allParameters['productId']]);
             }
             //Check paramter for maximum no. of product per page
             if(array_key_exists("pageSize",$allParameters)){
                $collection->setPageSize($allParameters['pageSize']);
             }
             //Check paramter for current page no. 
             if(array_key_exists("page",$allParameters)){
                $collection->setCurPage($allParameters['page']);
             }
            $result=$collection->getData();
            return $result;
    }

}
```

In above method first apply filter on Store ID and then optional parameters pass in URL like customer_id,product_id.
Special check for parameters name.

Step 5. In last create registration.php in MyReviews folder.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'ECMAG_MyReviews',
    __DIR__
);
```

and call system upgrade command->  php bin/magento setup:upgrade

after all above process call url as -`http://hostname/magento/index.php/rest/V1/showreview/allreviews/1'

also when pass parameters in url like-
`http://hostname/magento/index.php/rest/V1/showreview/allreviews/1?productId=1'

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I will follow these step then tell its working or not. Thanks for help.

Comment: Thank you for your support.its really helpful.